# Pandas exponential power not computing as it should

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, precision

I think I found an issue with floating point precision when using exponents in PANDAs. I had a list of numbers I was running through a 4th order polynomial, when I got to orders greater than 2 I noticed that the values being predicted in Pandas were not correct. Code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = [-69500]
x_k = pd.DataFrame([i*1000 for i in x], columns=['X'])

x_k3 = x_k**3
x_k3_np = np.power(x_k['X'], 3)


x_k3_real = [pow(i*1000, 3) for i in x]



print(x_k3.iloc[0])
print(x_k3_np.iloc[0])
print(x_k3_real[0])
```

Produces:

```
X   -8526346633579692032
Name: 0, dtype: int64
-8526346633579692032
-335702375000000000000000
```

As is indicated the list comprehension method produces the answer I would consider correct - but not sure why Pandas wouldnt. Is there a better way to do this in a dataframe?

Comment: Where do you see floating point? Doesn't look like a precision issue, either, but like overflow. Doesn't the `int64` indicate the issue?

Comment: I dont see floating point anywhere - but I am wondering if when the variable is stored in memory if the ```**``` operation is unreliable for large numbers? Could you explain more how ```int64`` indicates the issue? Why is that telling?

Comment: Because your number [clearly exceeds 64 bits](https://www.google.com/search?q=log2(335702375000000000000000)).

Comment: If you take -335702375000000000000000 modulo 2^64 you get -8526346633579692032